# Function preserves state

Tags: c++, qt

Every node (`Node` is a class that inherits `QGraphicsItem`) has its own `id`. When I click on the item I want that `id` to be passed to the `inputDialog` (inherits `QInputDialog`). And that's fine for the first item I hit.

Unfortunately, every other item I click on, shows the `id` of the first item that was hit. Funny thing is, `id` is a private member, and `inputDialog` is no friend to `Node`. Moreover, when I get rid of the `input.exec()` line everything is fine. How is that possible?

```
void Node::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
    Q_UNUSED(event);
    qDebug() << id;
    inputDialog input(id);
    input.exec();
}
```

Rest of the code is plain simple:

```
class Node : public QGraphicsItem
{
public:
    Node(QPointF);
    QRectF boundingRect() const;
    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget);
protected:
    void mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event);
private:
    static int key;
    int id;
};

Node::Node(QPointF point):id(key){
    setPos(point);
    key++;
    qDebug() << id;
}

int Node::key = 0;

inputDialog::inputDialog(int i, QWidget *parent) :
    QInputDialog(parent), id(i)
{

}
```

Comment: What does the qDebug() output?

Comment: Does `inputDialog` have another constructor that takes only `int i` argument ?

Comment: @Rostislav yes, qDebug() does output

Comment: @Manos, inputDialogs' constructor has one implicit argument(in the header file)